# Tensorflow: Scale weights to fit new model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to utilize weights from a checkpoint that have a shape of (784, 62) with a new model who's weights are (4096, 62).  I first began by trying to resize the old weights as one would with a picture, but that did not work.  Is there any way to somehow 'scale' the old weights to fit the model of the new and still maintain their accuracy?  Besides the increased shape, both models are exactly the same.

I am happy to provide any code of my program upon request.

Comment: No, simply there is not.

Comment: the reason it didnt work at all it was because u had to scale down the values of the weights too, of course this method will not work always. i would try scalling the weights based on the ratio of the shapes 784/4096 = 0.1914 => i would multiply the new weights in the larger shape with that value